# Hosting of My ASP.NET Core Web Application With Kestrel Only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-hosting

I just want to host my ASP.NET web application (not MVC) only in my local network for access from several tablets and PCs. I don't want to use any web servers like NGINX (which is very good on Linux but horrible on Windows as far as I concerned), Apache or IIS. I have PC with Windows 10 on board intended to be used as a web server.
What I learned about possible solutions. All articles say that it is impossible to use web servers like IIS or Apache separately from Kestrel (only as an external reverse web server to Kestrel web server with out-of-process hosting model) but however Microsoft articles say that it is possible to use Kestrel solely as an edge but they describe only usage of out-of-process model and I found no detailed instructions for configuration of only Kestel as a web server. So my questions are the following:

1. Can I use Kestrel only as a web server with in-of-process hosting model (which is default for ASP.NET applications as far as I know)? Does it means that the way described in this article is the only one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio ? Honestly I've got a feeling that usage of Kestrel only is impossible with in-of-process hosting model.
2. Can somebody give me a link to detailed instructions on how to configure hosting of ASP.NET application with Kestrel only with in-of-process or out-of-process hosting model? Or perhaps just tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in-of-process or out-of-process hosting mode

in/out-of-process is about hosting ASP.NET Core app under IIS. If you don't want any other web server - you don't need to. You just create a ASP.NET Core and run the app that's it, [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel) is build-in. For example in the following setup:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

`UseKestrel` is called internally by `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`.

Docs (though I think you have already seen that):

- [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/).
- [Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)
- [Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)

Comment: So can I just add my executable file to Windows auto-startup so it started automatically after I turned on my Windows 10 PC and it will start Kestrel along with my web app? Did I understood it correctly?

Comment: @Torrvic yes, exactly